# ServiceStack: Dependency injected object's lifetime in IMessageService

Tags: dependency-injection, servicestack, inversion-of-control, message-queue

We have logic that implements `IMessageService.RegisterHandler<T>(Func<IMessage<T>, object>)`. In the execution block of the message queue, we auto-wire a service by using Funq.Container. The service's properties were dependency injected but appear to be shared among threads. The property class is defined like:

```
_Container.RegisterAutoWired<DbConnectionManager>().ReusedWithin(Funq.ReuseScope.Request);
```

Most of the time, the DbConnectionManager property is created as a new object. However, during some extremely busy time, we notice that the DbConnectionManager is reused among threads and causing problems.

My question is: what's the appropriate lifetime setting for dependency injected objects which are used by both web requests and in message queues? And any insights on this particular problem that we have experienced? Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use Request scope for MQ Requests. If the dependency is ThreadSafe use the default singleton registration:

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<DbConnectionManager>();
```

Otherwise if it's not thread-safe register it as a transient dependency:

```
container.RegisterAutoWired<DbConnectionManager>().ReusedWithin(ReuseScope.None);
```

Comment: Thanks @mythz. This confirms my suspicion of the cause of the problem. However, in the circumstances that this DbConnectionManager is also used by a lot ordinary services, in which we need to keep one instance per request, I can't think of other ways but creating a separate DbConnectionManagerForMQ class to use ReuseScope.None. Is that something suggested?

Comment: @JamesChen Using Request Scope is almost always a bad idea, either the dependency is Thread Safe in which case use a singleton or it's not in which case use transient. When you need the performance implement pooling behind a singleton dependency API and release the instance back into the pool immediately after usage which minimizes resource contention. If you need to share objects throughout the Request Pipeline use `IRequest.Items` dictionary. I can't think of a single good reason to use Request Scope.

Comment: we have some different logic that does DB operations in their own code blocks. When we composite them in a hierarchical structure, we want to have a single DbConnection and Transaction so we introduce this DbConnectionManager as a DbConnection wrapper to avoid nested transactions. Transient type doesn't work in that way. I'm also thinking using ReuseScope.Container and manage child-containers in web requests and MQ. Do you reckon it's a valid approach?

Comment: @JamesChen I don't, I'd never leak transaction scopes outside of execution boundaries.

Comment: Thanks for your great insights, @mythz! We may need some time to modify our code to follow your suggestions but they are definitely valuable to follow.